# Apache-storm Supervisor dies when it tries to run topology in the multi-node environment

Tags: submit, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, topology

I'm doing the simplest zookeeper / storm / topology / muti-node test.

Everything is fine, but the supervisor dies at the last stage (when the storm supervisor tries to run the topology).

I have 3 VM(ubuntu-16.04.2.)hosts.

Each host has the same environment (including dependencies):

- zookeeper-3.4.10

- apache-storm-1.1.1

The names of the three hosts:

storm-nimbus: This id nimbus host.

storm-sv-1: This is first supervisor.

storm-sv-2: This is second supervisor.

The three hosts have the same configuration part of /etc/hosts .

```
192.168.3.132 zk1.nf.dev st1.nf.dev
192.168.3.130 zk2.nf.dev st2.nf.dev
192.168.3.131 zk3.nf.dev st3.nf.dev
```

zoo.cfg

```
...
dataDir=/home/test/1/zookeeper/data/

server.1=zk1.nf.dev:2888:3888
server.2=zk2.nf.dev:2888:3888
server.3=zk3.nf.dev:2888:3888
...
```

storm.yaml

```
...
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "zk2.nf.dev"
     - "zk3.nf.dev"

nimbus.seeds: ["st1.nf.dev"]

storm.local.dir: "/home/test/1/storm-local"
...
```

---Test steps---

1) Run the zookeeper server on those three hosts. 
   Test zookeeper status using zkCli.sh. 3 zookeeper nodes are fine.

2) Run storm ui on the nimbus host(192.168.3.132)

3) Run storm nimbus on the nimbus host(192.168.3.132)

4) Verify nimbus status in the ui page(http://192.168.3.132:8080/). That's fine.

5) Submit wordcount topology on the nimbus host(192.168.3.132)

Verify topology status in the ui page. That's OK.

6) Run storm supervisor on the supervisor hosts(192.168.3.130, 192.168.3.131).

7) Verify supervisor and topology status in the ui page.

- Two supervisors appear on the UI page. : OK
- In every supervisor page:

  - "Slots" and "Avali slots" are not 0. : OK
  - "Used slots" is always 0. : This is problem.

8) After abount 2 minutes supervisor died

[supervisor.log]

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: storm-nimbus
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:221) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:105) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:53) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:100) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    ... 13 more
2017-11-11 19:33:40.991 o.a.s.l.AsyncLocalizer Async Localizer [WARN] Failed to download basic resources for topology-id WordCount-1-1510457397
2017-11-11 19:33:40.992 o.a.s.d.s.AdvancedFSOps Async Localizer [INFO] Deleting path /home/test/1/storm-local/supervisor/tmp/f645cbdf-c2d2-493f-917b-7d2e82e84ef5
2017-11-11 19:33:41.019 o.a.s.d.s.AdvancedFSOps Async Localizer [INFO] Deleting path /home/test/1/storm-local/supervisor/stormdist/WordCount-1-1510457397
2017-11-11 19:33:41.023 o.a.s.l.AsyncLocalizer Async Localizer [WARN] Caught Exception While Downloading (rethrowing)... 
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [st1.nf.dev]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:111) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:57) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.blobstore.NimbusBlobStore.prepare(NimbusBlobStore.java:268) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.getClientBlobStoreForSupervisor(Utils.java:538) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.downloadBaseBlobs(AsyncLocalizer.java:121) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.call(AsyncLocalizer.java:148) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.call(AsyncLocalizer.java:101) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
2017-11-11 19:33:41.027 o.a.s.d.s.Slot SLOT_6700 [ERROR] Error when processing event
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [st1.nf.dev]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.LocalDownloadedResource$NoCancelFuture.get(LocalDownloadedResource.java:63) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.handleWaitingForBasicLocalization(Slot.java:413) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.stateMachineStep(Slot.java:273) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.run(Slot.java:741) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
Caused by: org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [st1.nf.dev]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:111) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:57) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.blobstore.NimbusBlobStore.prepare(NimbusBlobStore.java:268) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.getClientBlobStoreForSupervisor(Utils.java:538) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.downloadBaseBlobs(AsyncLocalizer.java:121) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.call(AsyncLocalizer.java:148) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.call(AsyncLocalizer.java:101) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
2017-11-11 19:33:41.027 o.a.s.u.Utils SLOT_6700 [ERROR] Halting process: Error when processing an event
java.lang.RuntimeException: Halting process: Error when processing an event
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.exitProcess(Utils.java:1773) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.run(Slot.java:774) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
2017-11-11 19:33:41.032 o.a.s.d.s.Supervisor Thread-5 [INFO] Shutting down supervisor ce5768f3-787d-4e27-9bb0-857bb1015139
2017-11-11 19:33:41.036 o.a.s.e.EventManagerImp Thread-4 [INFO] Event manager interrupted
```

Every test time I have cleared zookeeper data and storm temporary data.

How can I resolve follow error message : "Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [st1.nf.dev]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?"

Ping to 'st1.nf.dev' is OK. Why supervisor cant find 'st1.nf.dev'?

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop storm
2. Connect to zookeeper using command line

   ```
   ..path to zookeeper bin/zkCli.sh 
   rmr /storm 
   quit
   ```
3. Restart storm

Comment: Really helpful after upgrading Apache storm from 1.2.2 to 2.2.0